# How count the 1's and 0's with a bit return type and return it in two separate columns

Tags: c#, sql

I would like my sql query to select all the fields in a table by one date or between two dates, 3 of the fields in my database have the return type as bits. This is somewhat my database looks

```
ID||Name || Surname || Age || Country || SumOfInfection || SumOfOtherInfection|| HasPersonContacted
```

SumOfInfection, SumOfOtherInfection& HasPersonContacted have the return type of bits. For these three fields i; need to sum the numbers of True(1) and False(0) into two separate columns.

Name|| Surname|| .... ||HasPersonContacted(sum of 1's based on a userID) || HasPersonContacted(sum of 0's based on a userID) .....
so what i am looking for

```
SumOfInfection <- all the 1's for that ID
output= 10 <- so the person had 10 infection
SumOfInfection <- all the 0's for that ID
output= 3 - so the person had no infection for 3 times
```

i would like to do same for SumOfOtherInfection and HasPersonContacted .

This is what i have done but it only shows the sum of SumOfInfection how do i get all these data in one go? i rely like to use Select * because in future if i am looking for more data i dont have to rewrite my query.

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(SumOfInfection,1)) 
From [TableName] 
where ID='1234' AND Cast([Time] AS DATE) >'2012-01-09' AND CAST([Time] AS DATE) < '2014-01-01'
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you mean that when `SumOfInfection`, `SumOfOtherInfection` and `HasPersonContacted` have a value of `1`, you want to return `3`? Then what's wrong with something like `SumOfInfection + SumOfOtherInfection + HasPersonContacted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conditional `sum()`:

```
SELECT sum(case when SumOfInfection = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NumInfection1,
       sum(case when SumOfInfection = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NumInfection0
From [TableName] 
where ID='1234' AND Cast([Time] AS DATE) >'2012-01-09' AND CAST([Time] AS DATE) < '2014-01-01' ;
```

Alternatively, you can cast the bit as an integer:

```
SELECT sum(cast(SumOfInfection as int)) as NumInfection1,
       sum(1 - cast(SumOfInfection as int)) as NumInfection1
```

EDIT:

I think the full query is more like:

```
select Name, Surname,
       sum(case when HasPersonContacted = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NumPersonContacted1,
       sum(case when HasPersonContacted = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NumPersonContacted0,
       . . .
from t
group by Name, Surname;
```

Comment: yes that's what i needed. Now how do i get a person's name, surname etc...?

Comment: i am getting the error saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where' so before from table i added the date. if i run the query without dates then i get error saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'

Comment: @Dip . . . If I had to guess, you have a comma at the end of the last line in the `select`.

Comment: it works. can i add this calculation on my INNER JOIN table. so fname and sname i am getting for one table and other fields i am getting from second table so my query looks: `SELECT name, sname etc.... from tablename INNER JOIN table1 field ON table1.ID = table1.ID`. how would i implement the 0's and 1's calculation in INNER JOIN

Comment: @Dip . . . Either the same way or using a subquery in the `from` clause.  If you have a particular problem in mind, you might want to ask another question.